# Varchar to Numeric Exception

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I realize this has been asked a million times, but I can't find an answer that works. New to sql server and vs 2010 vb (complain to the boss, not me), doing practice runs. Continually getting a varchar to numeric exception in the following:

```vb
Dim height, width As Decimal

        height = InputBox("Enter height:")
        width = InputBox("Enter width:")

        'PRODUCING VARCHAR TO NUMERIC EXCEPTION
        command = New SqlCommand("DECLARE @height as decimal(10,2), " & _
                                 "@width as decimal(10,2), " & _
                                 "@area as decimal(10,2); " & _
                                 "SET @height = ' " & height & " '; " & _
                                 "SET @width = ' " & width & " '; " & _
                                 "SET @area = @height * @width; " & _
                                 "IF @height IS NULL OR @width IS NULL " & _
                                 "     SELECT 'Either the height or width field was blank.' " & _
                                 "ELSE IF @height <= 0 OR @width <= 0 " & _
                                 "     SELECT 'That''s some fancy negative space.' " & _
                                 "ELSE " & _
                                 "     SELECT 'The area is: ' +@area;" _
                                 , connect)
        connect.Open()
        rdr = command.ExecuteReader()
```

I have verified via vartype() that the data being passed is indeed decimal (I'm the only one testing, so not worried about that error control atm). I have tried using the variables with and without the enclosing single quotes. Cast() and Convert() are not working (unless I'm doing them incorrectly?). Not sure where the problem is?

Comment: Don't use string substitution to build sql. It leaves you open to some really nasty security issues.

Comment: Why go to database when you can do the same thing in vb.net?

Comment: Check locale, `10.0` vs `10,0` and decimal point separator

Comment: As Joel suggested you really need to parameterize your queries to avoid sql injection. You should do some research on sql injection and see just how nasty things can get when you execute code from the user.

Comment: The database is useless in your example. Usually these things are done in the vb.net side. Why are you doing it like this?

Comment: "doing practice runs" i will eventually be converting an access database to sql server. i'm learning the process before actual attempts at execution.

i've not gotten to parameters yet. i'm still learning.|

i'm looking for an answer to the varchar to numeric exception and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Dim height, width As Decimal
height = InputBox("Enter height:")
width = InputBox("Enter width:")

'PRODUCING VARCHAR TO NUMERIC EXCEPTION
command = New SqlCommand("IF @height IS NULL OR @width IS NULL " & _
                         "     SELECT 'Either the height or width field was blank.' " & _
                         "ELSE IF @height <= 0 OR @width <= 0 " & _
                         "     SELECT 'That''s some fancy negative space.' " & _
                         "ELSE " & _
                         "     SELECT 'The area is: ' + cast(@width * @height as varchar(20))" _
                    , connect)

command.Parameters.Add("@height", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = height
command.Parameters.Add("@width", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = width
connect.Open()
rdr = command.ExecuteReader()
```

Also, it's very strange to write IF/ELSE statements in SQL to choose among various selects. For SQL, you want to think in terms of writing a single statement that describes a set of data.

Comment: And that query is not even using the database.  It could have all been done without making a call to the db server.

Comment: Definitely... but I get the sense he's just trying to get sql to do _anything_ at this point. Baby steps.

Comment: i'll try this, thank you! i haven't gotten so far in my learning to understand parameters yet, but this is a great heads up.

as for the if else, it's just play to see what happens when the vars are passed...i know it needs tweaking. and yes, you are very correct. i'm just trying to understand the sql.